# There was an error running the selected code generator Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.SqlServer

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Add an ASP.NET Core MVC controller with views, using Entity Framework Core.

I get this error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator Microsoft.EntityFramework.Core.SqlServer

What is the problem?

Comment: Difficult for anyone to tell from a distance, no? Check the build output; increase the verbosity of the build output in the settings if necessary. You should find details of the error right above this message.

Comment: The problem is visual studio...Not in any other project ....All give the same error

Comment: I'm sure. That doesn't invalidate my comment, though. Increasing build verbosity should still give some details (since code generators run at compile time). You can also try alternative methods of creating and/or building the project (`dotnet new`/`dotnet build` from the command line).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which tutorial you followed for your requirement?